Cut and combine videos
I am a university lecturer. I have been using KDEnlive for my online lecture videos. However, the deficits of this approach have become unbearable:

I merely want to cut Zoom recordings or combine them.
KDenlive bloats up recordings multiple times of the original file size
The rendering takes several minutes, proportional to the video size

I would like to find a software that serves my purposes better:

works with Zoom recordings
combine video parts, cut out unused parts of the video
do not inflate the file size and do not take nonsensical time to render


I'd be inclined to blame that on inadequate codec choice, rather than on the software as a whole

Any OS or price/gratis details you can add to your question/tags?

I personally use DaVinci Resolve (free version) on Windows. But the software support also MacOS and Linux. You can do all the operations you want (and more). The good news is this software use GPU to speedup the rendering process (as well as preview effects, filters, etc). Also it support good amount of output containers and codecs. One serious challenge is the manual is 4000 pages so it will take some time to learn it in deep.

For a free, open source & cross platform solution I use Python & MoviePy (which in turn downloads & uses FFMPEG). You could use FFMPEG directly but the MoviePy approach avoids very long command lines.
This allows me to cut & splice time segments of the recording, to render it in a more compact form & optionally to resize, title, caption & insert still shots for things like slides or other diagrams. (Inkscape is required for captions).
Rendering/Reencoding operations generally take a fraction of the recording length but it does depend on the amount of reencoding, the complexity of the operations. drive speeds & the available processing power.

Try videocut for cutting and videomerge for merging. Both have been written for Linux (not Windows). Both have been written by me due to missing alternatives on that platform.

Lossless-cut is a simple, yet fast and powerful way of cutting videos in a lossless way without re-encoding them. This makes cutting ultra-fast and keeps the size of the parts identical to the original video.
This is gratis open-source offline video-editing for windows, linux and mac
Here's an example video where 3 pieces shall be kept:

Pros:

it's immediately clear which parts will be deleted, indicated by a trash symbol
it's super fast
it's as simple as pressing 3 buttons:

slide the cursor to the beginning of a scene
press the begin button (hand on the left)
slide the cursor to the end of that scene
press the end button (hand on the right)
press the export button


it snaps to keyframes by default (you typically want that)

Cons:

the begin hand and end hand buttons are had to distinguish. But you get used to it
the Windows version does not have an installer. It's portable only. So you don't get an entry in the start menu (some people want that)

It can also merge, i.e. put them in sequence, but this only works if the videos use identical codecs. This is a technical limitation IMHO, since there's no video file format that supports different codecs in a single file. Again, merging videos is quite simple. Drag'n'drop the second file on the UI and it will offer a merge dialog. Enable the Compatibility check to see if the codecs are identical.
Here's how merging looks like:

And in case of an incompatible codec, a warning may be shown:

Pros:

again, simple to use
super fast
Cons:
compatibility check should be on by default, but is off by default, which may produce invalid files

